# BMO2 2006 - Optimal Arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

*An exam consisting of six questions is sat by $2006$ children. Each
question is marked either right or wrong. Any three children have
right answers to at least five of the six questions between them. Let $N$
be the total number of right answers achieved by all the children (i.e.
the total number of questions solved by child $1$ + the total solved by
child $2$ + · · · + the total solved by child $2006$). Find the least possible
value of $N$.*

So I've begun by trying to find an optimal arrangement and seeing if I can prove that this is the best I can do. $6 \choose 4$ $ = 15$, so we can have up to $30$ children getting fewer than $5$ questions right, since otherwise there will always be $3$ who have the same four questions. Hence, at least $2006-30 = 1976$ got five questions right. So, we can make a configuration so that the least of $N$ is at most $1976 \times 5 + 30 \times 4 = 10000$.

Now I am struggling to prove that the least possible value of $N$ is indeed 10000.

I would also be very grateful if anyone that has a rich collection of these kinds of problems involving finding the best arrangement and proving that it is the best could comment with a link to them.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the bipartite graph, whose set $X$ is the set of children with less than 5 correct answers, and $Y$ the set of all possible $4$-subsets of the six questions.  We join an edge between $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ if the correct answers of $x$ is a subset of $Y$.

Then each $y\in Y$ has at most 2 neighbours, as you observed, so at most 30 members of $X$, so the minimum $N$ is $\leq 10000$ as you demonstrated.

On the other hand, if a child $x$ answers $m<4$ correct, then $x$ is joined to $\binom{6-m}{4-m}=\binom{6-m}{2}$ members of $Y$.  So this removes $\binom{6-m}{2}-1>4-m$ elements of $X$ (so this number of additional child(ren) must answer at least 5 questions correctly), so $N\geq 10000$.